# I have file names listed in files and want to read the content of the files row by row.The below code considers the file name itself as a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

glob reads all the files with .csv extension and writes it to files.I want to write a code to read the contents of each of the csv files listed in files.files is a

```
list ={file1.csv,file2.csv,file3.csv}
```

when I read x row by row the `o/p` is

```
file2.csv f i l e 2 . c s v
```

Comment: CODE::for files in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    #print(files)
    #print("next for loop")
    x=files
    print(x)
    for row in x:
      print(row)

Comment: That's not a list, it's not even valid Python syntax. You need quotes around your strings, and a list is in `[]`, not `{}`.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on how to read from files in Python. You're just printing the filename, not opening the file and reading it.

Answer (score -1):

As others have commented, this is not reading the files, and that is not proper syntax for a list. A list uses `[]`, not `{}`, which is used by dictionaries. You can provide a list of filenames like `fnames=['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv']` and iterate through that list to open each.

```py
fnames=['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv']
fdict={} # Create a dict to store contents of files in with fname as key
for fname in fnames:
    with open(fname,'r') as f:
        fdict[fname]=f.readlines()
```